# Regex that matches variable assignments ("a=12") but ignores function assignments ("f(x)=x^2")

Tags: javascript, regex

I am getting better with regex, but get stuck with things like this:

I am using the regex: `^\s*(\S*\w\S*)\s*=(.*)$`
to identify/match assignments of variables, e.g. `a = 12` or `length = 3`, which works flawlessly.

My recent problem:

I need to **prevent** the regex from catching/matching, if there is a function assignment, for instance:

```
f(x) = x^2
```

Because the regex above still catches the "variable" `f(x)`.

How can I modify the regex so that it still works but ignores the "variable" if there is an opening bracket `(`.

That all those examples get ignored: `f(x)=…`, `g(x)=…`, `test(x)=…`

JS Code:

```
var lineRegExp = /^\s*(\S*\w\S*)\s*=(.*)$/;
var match = lineRegExp.exec(line);
if(match) { ... }
```

Comment: Close flag for "too broad"? I think the question is quite specific.

Comment: You can just use: `^\s*(\w+)\s*=(.+)$` as variable name should not contain other special characters also like `%, &, *, {, \, ;` etc.

Comment: What is the purpose of `\S` in your regex, why not using simple `^\s*(\w+)\s*=(.*)$`?

Comment: Are you parsing JavaScript code? There are some good libraries for that.

Comment: I am developing a calculator webapp based on Javascript, where you can do arbitrary calculations (mathjs does the magic) and now even define own functions like f(x) = x^x and call them by f(2). See here "Notizrechner" with an example: https://www.matheretter.de/notiz?n=1r8j8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable names can be matched by `[A-Za-z_]\w*`, so you can simply use:

`^\s*([A-Za-z_]\w*)\s*=\s*(.*)`

to match just variable assignments instead.

Comment: `(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*)` will also match [`f("1 = 1");`](https://regex101.com/r/pZDUiR/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, it doesn't: `/(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*)/.test('f(" = 1")') === false`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir You are testing against another string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Don't forget that OP surrounds his version of the [**regex**](https://regex101.com/r/4bfzAz/3) by `^` and `$`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir `$` is unnecessary since the `.*` at the end of the regex would match and consume all characters until the end of the line (since the OP is processing one line at a time).

Comment: @blhsing Correct. I'm just saying that OP's use of the regex makes it impossible to match `f("1 = 1")`.

Comment: I am using your first answer `(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*)` now. Seems to work for my use cases. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can test it live:

```js
var txt = document.getElementById("txt");
txt.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
  txt.style.backgroundColor=/^ *[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*? *= *?[^\s]+$/i.test(txt.value)?"#0f0":"#f00";
});
```

```html
<input type='text' id='txt' placeholder='type here'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this pattern `^(?![^=\(]*\([^=\)]*\)).+`.

It matches eveyrthing, unless there are **both**, opening and closing bracket (`(` and `)`). It achieves it with negative lookahead `(?![^=\(]*\([^=\)]*\))`, which assures that we won't have opening and closing bracket **before* equality operator `=` (thanks to negative character class `[^=\(]`).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FzCqg8/1)